# Array index 1 is out of bounds (overflow) when widening date range

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am running the following query to return the top purchased category per user, this works fine on date ranges of 30 days and 60 days, but when I try and run it over the past 100 days I get the error:

`Array index 1 is out of bounds (overflow)`

Why is the widening the date range causing this error?

```
WITH `query_result` AS (

SELECT customDimension.value AS UserID,
SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(hits_product.v2ProductName) LIKE "% mens%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS mens,
SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(hits_product.v2ProductName) LIKE "%womens%" THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS womens,
SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(hits_product.v2ProductName) LIKE "%boys%" 
OR LOWER(hits_product.v2ProductName) LIKE "%girls%"
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS kids
FROM `xxx.xxx.ga_sessions_20*` AS t
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits) AS hits
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(t.customdimensions) AS customDimension
  CROSS JOIN UNNEST(hits.product) AS hits_product
WHERE parse_date('%y%m%d', _table_suffix) between 
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 100 day) and
DATE_sub(current_date(), interval 1 day)
AND customDimension.index = 2
AND hits.eCommerceAction.action_type = "6"
GROUP BY UserID
HAVING
SUM(CASE WHEN LOWER(hits_product.v2ProductName) LIKE "%boys%" 
OR LOWER(hits_product.v2ProductName) LIKE "%girls%"
THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
)
  SELECT *, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY(
    SELECT SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)]
    FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(REGEXP_REPLACE(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'[{"}]', ''))) kv
    WHERE LOWER(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)]) <> LOWER('UserID')
    ORDER BY CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ), ',') top_purchased_gender
FROM `query_result` t
```

Comment: Maybe one of your `kv` values doesn't have the format you're expecting? You could try SAFE_OFFSET instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just use `[safe_offset (1)]` instead of `[offset (1)]` then handle null exception

like this:

```
ORDER BY CAST(ifnull(SPLIT(kv, ':')[safe_offset (1)], 0) AS INT64) DESC
```

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#array_subscript_operator

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/conditional_expressions#ifnull

Answer (score 0):

at least one of the rows has a field with an empty value where an array should be, with a null or empty instead of an empty array.
it is not in the last 30 days or in the last 60 days but in the last 100 days you do have at least on occurrence. and that is making your sql jump.
you need to set your default values accordingly (with an empty array or a function that guarantees an array with the minimum number of fields that you will be searching for) and not allow this field to be null.